# Material DatePicker error (Type MatDatepicker is not assignable to type...)

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I've a simple form field

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="flex-grow-1" style="padding: 0 5px;">
            <mat-label>Data di nascita</mat-label>
            <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="selectableDates" [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="birthDate">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
```

where the filter is

```
selectableDates = (date: Date | null): boolean => {
    return (date || new Date()) < new Date();
};
```

Everything it seems to work properly but my ide show me this error

[image]

and I'm not able to push the files on the server.

Can you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong? I've also tried to use this example https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-validation, but I've the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your filter like this:

```
selectableDates: boolean = (d: Date | null) => (d ?? new Date()) < new Date();
```

1. As a general rule, try not to use **"reserved words"** alike as the name of your variables (for instance, the 'date' name of your variable).
2. If the fat arrow is just a return (without other operations in between), you don't need the **"curly braces"**.
3. If your angular version allows it, use ?? instead || (it is not necessary, but just to try...)

If none of this worked fine, try with this other approach to your code:

```
selectableDates = (d: Date | null): boolean => {
    const today = new Date();
    const myDate = d || today;

    return ( myDate < today );
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately no solution seems to work :(

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't help you. Could you make a 'stackblitz'? Maybe this will make it easier for someone else to help you with new ideas.